# Error in my Java Program '.class' expected

Tags: java

```
class TwoDimArryAlloc {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       int itemno[][] = new int[][] {  {2234,2235,2236,2237,2238}  ,   {3334,3335,3336,3337,3338}  };
       int it;

       String itemdesc[][] = new String[][] {{"Womans Item1","Womans Item2","Womans Item3","Womans Item4","Womans Item5"},{"Mans  Item1","Mans Item2","Mans Item3","Mans Item4","Mans Item5"}};


       for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
       {
           for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
           {
               System.out.println(itemno[][]);
           }
       }
  }
}
```

In the above program, I got the following error:

```
C:\Java Programs\TwoDimArryAlloc.java:18: '.class' expected
                System.out.println(itemno[][]);
                                             ^
1 error

Process completed.
```

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Comment: And please format your code correctly...

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the array index:

```
System.out.println(itemno[i][j]);
                          ^  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
System.out.println(itemno[][]);
```

you want to say

```
System.out.println(itemno[i][j]);
```

Without specifying which indexes you want, it is bad syntax, which confuses the compiler so much that it emits an impenetrable error message.

(The first pass of compilation is to construct a syntax tree, and this happens before the compiler figures out which names denote types and which ones denote variables. So when it sees `itemno[][]` it reasons that this *could* be the beginning of a valid expression if only `itemno` were the name of a type, but in that case the full expression would have to be `itemno[][].class` -- so that's what it asks for even though you meant something entirely different).

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    int itemno[][] = { {2234,2235,2236,2237,2238}  ,   {3334,3335,3336,3337,3338}  };
    int it;

    String itemdesc[][] = {{"Womans Item1","Womans Item2","Womans Item3","Womans Item4","Womans Item5"},{"Mans  Item1","Mans Item2","Mans Item3","Mans Item4","Mans Item5"}};


    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(""+itemno[i][j]); 
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to provide index in SYSO statement. Make it as follow:

```
System.out.println(itemno[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the indexes:

```
System.out.println(itemno[i][j]);
```